# Opinion on "CSS Centering an Unordered List"

Tags: html, css

In this question, I am not going to ask "How" to horizontally center an unordered list, because there are about eleventy thousand resources already on the internet for that.

Instead, I'd liked to ask the "WHY" part of it.

More precisely, why do we do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p9TbX/)

```
ul {
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
}
ul > li {
   position:relative;
   right: 50%;
}
```

instead of this:

```
ul {
   position:relative;
   left:25%;
}
```

When both seem to do the trick.
Any thoughts?

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: are you UL have any fixed width or it's dynamic ?

Comment: they are dynamic, with any number of elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, because the first method centers the `ul` in every case - indepentend on how many child `li` it has.

The second solution places the `ul` 25% to the right which will work in a very special case, when the widht of the `li` is just right to occupy 50% of the total width but breaks in any other case.

using `left` on the parent and `right` on the child is a very common practice to center a child with **dynamic** dimensions(width) which is the case when dealing with dynamic content.

In some cases, `text-align:center;` works too, but fails when you have to use absolute positioning.

See an [example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gGF9n/4/).

Comment: yup... i realized this a while later... the 25% trick works only in special cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using any of these solutions. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yz7jF/ .

Write like this:

```
ul {
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline;/*For IE7*/
   *zoom:1;/*For IE7*/
}
li{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}
.anyParent{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: ok solution, doesn't actually answer the "WHY" part of the question tho.

Comment: @Christoph can you please describe the cases in which is not working. So, it's good to know new things .

Comment: Easiest example for this method failing is on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: can create an example for the problem ?